# Calling an action from a different reducer with React and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got 2 components; A market and a status. The status component manage the amount of money the user have and the market have buttons to buy some stuff. When i click on the button (in the market component), i want my money to decrement.

How can i achieve this the best way possible?

This is my App component who has the Market and Status:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as MarketActions from '../actions/market-actions';
import * as StatusActions from '../actions/status-actions';

import Market from './Market.react';
import Status from './Status.react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { dispatch, market, status } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Link to='/'>App</Link>{' '}<Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
        <Status status={status} {...bindActionCreators(StatusActions, dispatch)} />
        <Market market={market} {...bindActionCreators(MarketActions, dispatch)} {...bindActionCreators(StatusActions, dispatch)} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ market: state.market, status: state.status }))(App);
```

I bound the actions from the status on the market component (i feel it's not the right thing to do, but it worked).

After this, i handle these actions in the Market component on a click of a button like this:

```
handleBuyClick(e) {
  let { index, price } = e.target.dataset;
  index = parseInt(index);
  price = parseInt(price);

  this.props.buyItem(index);
  this.props.changeMoney(price); //this bugs me, i think it don't belongs there
}
```

Is there a better way?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is bothering you? Both are fine approaches, and there's no significant difference between them. Are you concerned about firing two actions instead of one?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Why not react on the same action in both reducers? You could have code like this:

```
function status(state, action){
...
    switch(action.type){
        case BUY_ITEM: {
            return 'bought'
        }
    }
...
}

function market(state, action){
...
    switch(action.type){
        case BUY_ITEM: {
            return {...state, action.itemId : state[action.itemId] - 1 }
        }
    }
...
}
```

With whatever "reaction code" you need to perform.

Comment: So, i'll have just one dispatch?

Comment: @MikeBoutin yep, and just different reducers reacting on this dispatched action

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950185/change-states-array-without-changing-the-whole-state-react-redux

Comment: You're a genious!

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev What will be  action returning then because same action will trigger 2 reducer?

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala action creator will return action object `{type:'myAction'}` and all reducers will have code reacting to actions with `type === 'myAction'`, that's it.

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev Thanks, i got it now

Comment: What if "market", for proper reaction, needs to make some additional async requests?

Comment: @NikitaMartyanov looks like I don't fully understand what you mean. What you could do is fire async action from some middleware, so eventually `market` would have all the information it needs. Anyway, you have plain actions dispatched, which could lead both to new actions from middlewares or reducers changes